# "Excel" button does not appear in the DATATABLE plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using a DATATBLE and it includes all the buttons that the DATATBLE itself makes available. All appear except excel and the PDF button when clicking nothing happens.

Order of my imports:

```
define(
        ["jquery","jqueryui","bootstrap","bootstrap.datetimepicker","app/datatable","sweet-alert.min","jszip.min","dataTables.net-buttons","pdfmake.min",
        "vfs_fonts","buttons.html5.min","buttons.print.min"],
```

My DATATBLE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        tableInscricoes = $('#inscricoes').DataTable({
                            data: data,
                            pageLength: 50,
                            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                            buttons: [
                                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                            ],
                            // retrieve: true,
                            
                            columns: [
                                { title: "Selecione" },
                                { title: "Ação" },               
                                { title: "Curso" },
                                { title: "Série Escola" },
                                { title: "RA" },
                                { title: "Aluno" },
                                { title: "Turma Aut." },
                                { title: "Inscrição" },
                                { title: "Início Mat." },
                                { title: "Fim Mat." },
                                { title: "Dt. Cancel." },
                                { title: "Cancel. Por" },
                            ]
                        });   
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make datatables work properly, I suggest to use the [Datatable builder](https://datatables.net/download/), so it wont broke or have unexpected behavior.